# OSX/Swift Get Frontmost Running Application

Tags: swift, macos

I'm new to swift and osx programming in general, and I need help with one thing that I can't seem to find an answer for. I'm trying to get the frontmost application running on a computer through an app. Right now I'm able to detect when a target application opens, but not when it is in front of all other windows or when it goes into the background.
What I have so far is:

```
var workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
var applications = workspace.runningApplications
for app in applications {
    let x = "LolClient"
    if app.localizedName == x {
        println("League is open")
    }
}
```

That will just tell me when a target app opens. I just need to identify what app is in front of all others... basically which one is recieving keystrokes etc. What code would I need to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want [`NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1532097-frontmostapplication).

Comment: You referenced a local address on your own computer :p

Comment: Also... is there a way to get the 2nd frontmost application on swift? Or is this only for the frontmost application..

Comment: I don't know of a way.

Comment: @AnshulSingh Have you tried `let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication
```

For the name of the app:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication?.localizedName
```